# 90's Fantasy Cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, medieval

I can't seem to find any reference to it anywhere, or remember anything more than the following to narrow the search.

It was either late 80's or early 90's (I had it on video in early 90's).  It centred around this giant talking dragon'esq guy obsessed with getting this crystal/s (or something similar) from these gnomey creatures.  It was medieval fantasy style.

Help.  Bugging me to the nth!

Answer (score 10):

Could it be [The Dreamstone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TB8wRa9lQYQ&list=PLxel1_BYLrB0EIRFVS6vlCCDvbT2oI77N)? Big dragon dude called Zordrak, wanting to get hold of the Dreamstone to send nightmares to the world.

Comment: http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/villains/images/5/50/La_Pierre_des_Cauchemars.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20111024203058

Comment: Oh my gosh! I've been trying to remember this cartoon for YEARS! Thankyou so much for this!

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the 1982 film [*The Dark Crystal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083791/) ?

> Another planet, another time. 1000 years ago the mysterious Dark Crystal was damaged by one of the Urskeks and an age of chaos has began! The evil race of grotesque birdlike lizards the Skeksis, **gnomish dragons who rule their fantastic planet with an iron claw**. Meanwhile the orphan Jen, raised in solitude by a race of the peace-loving wizards called the Mystics, embarks on a **quest to find the missing shard of the Dark Crystal** which gives the Skesis their power and restore the balance of the universe.

Comment: Not a cartoon, of course. Jim Henson puppetry.